# All values go into one column in a table in Django. How to separate?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to **create a table** as an output, like in the picture below.

**views.py:**

```
test =  filtered_transaction_query_by_user.values('coin__name').annotate( total = (Sum('trade_price' ) * Sum('number_of_coins'))).order_by('-total')
```

**Desired outcome:**
[image: table]

**What I has tried:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Total Transactions table</h1>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Number of coins</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in test %}
    {{ item }}
    {% for key,value in item.items %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ value }}</td> 
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>
```

Can you please help me why all goes under the *Currency*, and not into the *Number of coins* column?

**Solution** thanks to @Willem Van Onsem

```
{% for item in test %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ item.coin__name }}</td><td>{{ item.total }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I have changed it to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render this with:

```
{% for item in test %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ item.coin__name }}</td><td>{{ item.total }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```